# Does affecting an action card affect the Minion it has been played on?

Tags: smash-up

Can an ongoing action card played on a minion be destroyed when an action played on a base is preventing minions from being affected?

For example:

A minion has **Tooth and Claw... and Guns** applied to it.

> Play on a minion. Ongoing: If an ability would affect this minion, destroy this card and the ability does not affect this minion.

If another player uses **Disenchant** on that minion,

> Destroy an action that has been played on a minion or base.

Would **Wildlife Preserve** (played on that base) block this entirely?

> Play on a base. Ongoing: Your minions here are not affected by other players' actions.

Does the play of the **Disenchant** destroy **Tooth and Claw... and Guns** and avoid the base card (**Wildlife Preserve**) since its play doesn't affect the minion?

Or, does this actually affect the minion by effectively "un-guarding" the minion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Does affecting an action card affect the Minion it has been played on?

**A:** No.

**Q:** Can an ongoing action card played on a minion be destroyed when an action played on a base is preventing minions from being affected?

**A:** Yes.

From the [most recent rules](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2014/11/SU7_Rulebook.pdf) (Pretty Pretty Smash Up), page 9:

> **Affect:** A card is affected if it is moved, returned, destroyed, placed, or is changed in power or controller, or has an action attached.

Removing an action is none of these. Even if you were removing an action that gave +2 power, the action doing the **removal** isn't changing the the minion's power.